# How to set X axis labels in MP Android Chart (Bar Graph)?

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

This is with reference to the article : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data  under the heading **Bar Graph**.In the given code below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph_test, container, false);

    BarChart chart = view.findViewById(R.id.bar_Chart_test);

    List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(0f, 30f));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(1f, 80f));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 60f));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(3f, 50f));
    // gap of 2f
    entries.add(new BarEntry(5f, 70f));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 60f));

    BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(entries, "BarDataSet");
    BarData data = new BarData(set);
    data.setBarWidth(0.9f); // set custom bar width
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.setFitBars(true); // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars
    chart.invalidate(); // refresh

    return view;
}
```

the output was:

Here the X values are not displayed.[Click here for the ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXwmq.png)

how to set the X-axis values as months(1st Jan,2nd Jan,3rd Jan.....) as displayed in the article.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just make a simple list of string like this :

```
final ArrayList<String> xAxisLabel = new ArrayList<>();
    xAxisLabel.add("Mon");
    xAxisLabel.add("Tue");
    xAxisLabel.add("Wed");
    xAxisLabel.add("Thu");
    xAxisLabel.add("Fri");
    xAxisLabel.add("Sat");
    xAxisLabel.add("Sun");
```

Then you do this :

```
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return xAxisLabel.get((int) value);

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still some problems coming.In the line : return xAxisLabel.get((int) value);  what is " value "?

Comment: value is the index here.

Comment: value is the number on xAxis as a label starting from left to right which can be negative, be careful when using it as an index. always make sure your graph has all default xAxis label which are not negative.

Comment: consider using  .setAxisMinimum(0);
        .setAxisMaximum(someNumber); to guarantee a positive range. Note: for some reason setting only .setAxisMinimum(0); won't work.

Comment: Hi @Sarthak Gandhi, can you please answer my bounty question regarding xAxis labels https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325511/mpandroid-chart-not-displaying-any-labels-for-xaxis-what-is-missing?noredirect=1#comment97407907_55325511

Comment: @SarthakGandhi , Thanks for help!. But doesn't this Override getFormattedValue function has to be implemented on BarData?    Like data.setValueFormatted = new ValueFormatter({...})

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?

Comment: Hey, Where is this ValueFormatter class?

Answer (score 18):

**Kotlin:**

```
val xAxisLabels = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ...)      
barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisLabels)
```

**Java:**

```
ArrayList<String> xAxisLables = new ArrayList();
xAxisLables.add("1");
xAxisLables.add("2");
xAxisLables.add("3");
xAxisLables.add("4"); ...

OR

String[] xAxisLables = new String[]{"1","2", "3", "4" ...};

barChartView.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisLables));
```

You can prepare any data you want in `xAxisLabels` to display

Comment: This should be the accepted solution for the latest version of the library

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?

Comment: @Moeez may be `xAsix.setLabelCount(...)` will help you

Answer (score 4):

For the `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3`

I am using a label list:

```
final List list_x_axis_name = new ArrayList<>();
list_x_axis_name.add("label1");
list_x_axis_name.add("label2");
list_x_axis_name.add("label3");
list_x_axis_name.add("label4");
list_x_axis_name.add("label5");
```

and setting the label like this:

```
BarChart chartBar = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chartBar);
XAxis xAxis = chartBar.getXAxis();
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-90);
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
 @override
 public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
  if (value >= 0) {
   if (value <= list_x_axis_name.size() - 1) {
    return list_x_axis_name.get((int) value);
   }
   return "";
  }
  return "";
 }
});
```

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?

Answer (score 3):

In dynamically set X axis label,

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();

xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getDate));

public ArrayList<String> getDate() {

        ArrayList<String> label = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++)
            label.add(yourList.get(i).getDateValue());
        return label;
    }
```

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?

Comment: @Moeez  please just try, adjust this value -  xAxis.setGranularity(1f);

Comment: I have already tried this `xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);` but same result

Comment: @Moeez Give the value xAxis.setGranularity(2f); then check the result; xAxis.setGranularity(0f); then check the result.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone needs a Kotlin version example, I customized it a bit:

```
val labels = arrayListOf(
    "Ene", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Abr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Ago", "Set",
    "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"
)

barChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels)
barChart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM

barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
barChart.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
barChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
barChart.description.isEnabled = false

val entries = arrayListOf(
    BarEntry(0f, 10f),
    BarEntry(1f, 20f),
    BarEntry(2f, 30f),
    BarEntry(3f, 40f),
    BarEntry(4f, 50f),
    BarEntry(5f, 60f),
    BarEntry(6f, 70f),
    BarEntry(7f, 60f),
    BarEntry(8f, 50f),
    BarEntry(9f, 40f),
    BarEntry(10f, 30f),
    BarEntry(11f, 20f)
)    
val set = BarDataSet(entries, "BarDataSet")
set.valueTextSize = 12f

barChart.data = BarData(set)    
barChart.invalidate()
```

- By default the xAxis labels are shown at the top. This example show them at the bottom.
- I also disabled the text description and the left and right axis (yes, by default we have 2 Y-axis at both sides).
- I decided to disable the grid and to increase the text size as well (it's small by default).

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?

Answer (score 0):

```
        HorizontalBarChart chart = findViewById(R.id.hbc_graph);   

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new BarEntry(0, 3f));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(1, 8f));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(2, 6f));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(3, 11f));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(4, 5f));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(5, 14f));

        BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries,"Horizontal Bar");

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSet);
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
        chart.invalidate();


        ArrayList<String> xLabels = new ArrayList<>();
        xLabels.add("January");
        xLabels.add("February");
        xLabels.add("March");
        xLabels.add("April");
        xLabels.add("May");
        xLabels.add("June");

        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                Print.e(value);
                return xLabels.get((int) value);
            }

        });
```

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379636/6854117) related to it can you please see it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> xMonth= new ArrayList<>();
            xMonth.add("January");
            xMonth.add("February");
            xMonth.add("March");
            xMonth.add("April");
            xMonth.add("May");
            xMonth.add("June");
XAxis xAxis = chartMth.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
   
                @Override
                public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                    return xMonth.get((int) value);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).